# `Open With` Error With Jar FIles?

Tags: command-line, kubuntu, 17.10, java, dolphin

I'm interested in opening `.jar` files that I develop using Dolphin's `open with` menu. I've ensured to make the jars executable and then found them using the open with menu. I always get the following error though (After having dolphin display the output to the console) Is there any way I can resolve this? NOTE: I have the JRE installed properly.

Strangely enough, double clicking the `.jar` opens it just fine

```
Warning: Could not start program '/home/sarah/NetBeansProjects/OPUS Converter/dist/OPUS_Converter.jar' with arguments '/home/sarah/NetBeansProjects/OPUS Converter/dist/OPUS_Converter.jar /home/sarah/NetBeansProjects/OPUS Converter/dist/README.TXT'.
Warning: execve: Exec format error
```

Comment: Have you installed binfmt-misc and jarwrapper (see https://askubuntu.com/q/917750/158442)?

Comment: You can't run java like this. You can write a .sh file to run your jar. That's what IntelliJ does. Even almost all the apache java projects does.

Comment: @dedunumax How would this work? If I want to use `open with` command to send the file to my Java application? What type of script would I have to write, and how would I pass the file location to my project?